# How to add a Prediction Resource to LUIS app programmatically

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I am using C# SDK to create the LUIS apps with required Intents, Utterances and Entities, and then training and Publishing the apps using an Authoring key created in Azure portal. After this, I use the REST Prediction endpoint for Intent matching, and till now I used the free Starter Prediction Key. After a month since the Starter key gets expired, I created a Cognitive service in Azure to be used as the Prediction resource. Now, how to add this new Prediction resource(Cognitive service) to my LUIS apps via SDK or REST? I am able to do so from LUIS Portal though, but don't want manual intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the prediction endpoint resource, the resource should be only used for endpoint prediction queries and not for authoring changes to the app. If you want to add the prediction resource to your app by not going through the portal and automate the assignment of the resource to a LUIS app for purposes like CI/CD pipeline, then you can follow the steps below:

- Get an Azure Resource Manager token from this [website](https://resources.azure.com/api/token?plaintext=true). This token does expire so use it immediately. The request returns an Azure Resource Manager token.
- Use the token to request the LUIS runtime resources across subscriptions, from the [Get LUIS azure accounts API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be313cec181ae720aa2b26c), which your user account has access to.

This POST API requires the following settings:

[image]

This API returns an array of JSON objects of your LUIS subscriptions including subscription ID, resource group, and resource name, returned as account name. Find the one item in the array that is the LUIS resource to assign to the LUIS app.

- Assign the token to the LUIS resource with the [Assign a LUIS azure accounts to an application](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5890b47c39e2bb17b84a55ff/operations/5be32228e8473de116325515) API.

This POST API requires the following settings:
[image]

When this API is successful, it returns a 201 - created status.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, can you please accept it so that it helps others?Thanks

Comment: Thanks, accepted. The only issue being, since I am doing every thing using SDK, it takes a lot of API calls to get things done. I mean to solve this, first I am generating a Token and then calling this API. A simple add default "Prediction Resource" for all apps on LUIS portal would have helped a lot. Anyways, thanks for this answer.

Comment: The official docs describe the process [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-azure-subscription#assign-a-query-prediction-runtime-resource-without-using-the-luis-portal)

Comment: Anyone else just get an empty array when following this process? I'm surprised and disappointed because I've got three LUIS apps and manually assigned Prediction Resources to them, so I would expect to get some stuff in my list. :(

Comment: Found an explanation for my empty array. My logged-in Azure user has access to multiple directories, and hitting the Azure Resource Manager token page above probably gave me a token for the wrong directory. I used the command line `az login` then `az account set -s {correct subscription}` and finally `az account get-access-token --resource=https://management.core.windows.net/ --query accessToken --output tsv`. That token gave me meaningful results back from the API.

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks, accepted. The only issue being, since I am doing every thing using SDK, it takes a lot of API calls to get things done. I mean to solve this, first I am generating a Token and then calling this API. A simple add default "Prediction Resource" for all apps on LUIS portal would have helped a lot. Anyways, thanks for this answer. – user3868541 Feb 3 at 9:45

Agreed that an Add default Prediction Resource would have made everything much better. I'm still not sure how to do this programmatically. I'm trying to do it in my service using the SDK

Comment: I was asked to review this answer. A quick glance indicates that it reads like a comment but I don't have all the context. If you are agreeing with another answer, please make that a comment.

Comment: Thanks! Not a comment but I'm adding to it because I don't think the response was really addressing the questions