# Different behaviour in new and previous luis portal

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I've found out that there are differences between current and previous luis portals regarding functionality. I'm talking about [eu.luis.ai](https://eu.luis.ai) (current) and [previous.eu.luis.ai](https://previous.eu.luis.ai) specifically.

For the scenario we assume the following:

1. There are multiple Azure Directories/tenants to which I was granted access
2. There is one authoring resource in a subscription in one of the ADs
3. There are multiple luis apps that belong to this authoring resource
4. I'm set as contributor in the authoring resource IAM
5. There are multiple prediction resources in different Azure Directories which I want to assign to these luis apps

In the **current portal** I select the Azure Directory via the profile menu. Within the selected AD I now can choose a authoring resource and then access the luis apps.
Now if I try to assign the prediction resources this is possible for prediction resources located in the Azure Directory I've selected. If I switch the AD, I would be able to assign the prediction resources of this AD but I'm not able to select the authoring resource of the other tenant and so I can't see any luis app.

In the **previous** portal I select the subscription and the authoring resource and then am able to access the luis apps. To assign the prediction resources I click the button "Add prediction resource" under the "Manage" tab of an app. A modal window opens where I can select a tenant, then a subscription of this tenant and then a prediction resource. So I'm able to assign any prediction resource of any tenant to which I was granted access to the luis apps that is registered to one authoring resource.

### And the question is

How can I assign any prediction resource of any tenant I was granted access to to a luis app that is linked with an authoring resource of a different tenant in the current luis portal?

Answer (score 0):

@ooorndtski The change in the new luis portal is to ensure the change in tenant is handled in the the same way as Azure portal. If you would like to assign a different prediction resource of different tenant you can use the programmatic API's. This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59966807/how-to-add-a-prediction-resource-to-luis-app-programmatically) details these steps.

Comment: The problem is that the concerning tenants do not own an O365 account; more precisely there is no e-mail adress assigned to that tenants that could be used to add them as contributor via IAM. For that reason it's not possible to add the prediction resources of different tenants using REST API, because the api call would return an 'Unauthorized' status.